# Installing Nginx on Debian 9

Tags: linux, debian, installation, nginx

Here is the deal, I am trying to install Nginx on my almost pure Debian 9 server. Basically I tried
sudo apt-get install nginx
and here is the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx : Depends: nginx-extras (>= 1:1.12.1-8.5.1.8~jessie1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: nginx-extras (< 1:1.12.1-8.5.1.8~jessie1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

input:

```
/etc/apt/source.list
```

output:

```
deb http://cdn-aws.deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb http://security.debian.org stretch/updates main
deb http://cdn-aws.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
```

input:

```
apt-cache policy nginx
```

output:

```
nginx:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 1:1.12.1-8.5.1.8~jessie1
  Version table:
 1:1.12.1-8.5.1.8~jessie1 500
    500 https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger jessie/main amd64 Packages
         .
         .
         .
 1:1.6.3-8.5.0.8~jessie1 500
    500 https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger jessie/main amd64 Packages
 1.10.3-1+deb9u1 500
    500 http://cdn-aws.deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
```

input:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

output:

```
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger jessie main
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger stretch main
```

Comment: can you also post the content of your `/etc/apt/source.list` ? In fact it seems that your repository binds *jessie* which is Debian 8

Comment: deb http://cdn-aws.deb.debian.org/debian stretch main  
deb http://security.debian.org stretch/updates main. 
deb http://cdn-aws.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main.
It is weird because I am using 9.

Comment: Update your question with the output of `apt-cache policy nginx`.
Looks like you indeed have some dependency problem.

Comment: please add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

Comment: Yeah, I added all details you want to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same question in stackoverflow for Ubuntu 14.04, I made a little change on it and voila!

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
```

and commented out.

```
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger jessie main
```

after that

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx nginx-extras
```

it was ok for my situation. Uncomment again

```
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger jessie main
```

And I was good to go.

Comment: Yes the problem come from `passenger.list`  which provide an old version of `nginx` compatible with debian jessie.